# Rails not compiling stylesheets in development after assets were precompiled

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline, stylesheet

I ran the command `rake assets:precompile` in my console, then my stylesheets stopped being compiled in my application.css file when I go to localhost:3000...

Before, everything was perfect on development mode : write a stylesheet, require it in the application.css file, then see the styles being displayed in my view. So the asset pipeline "used to" work.

What I did to try to make it work (and failed) using other answers on SOF:

1. In **config/application.rb** I added `config.assets.enabled = true`
2. in **config/development.rb** I added the following :

   - `config.serve_static_assets = false` so that Rails doesnt look for my stylesheet in the public/assets folder
   - `config.assets.compress = false`
   - `config.assets.debug = true` to see the traces of the css being loaded
   - `config.assets.compile = true`
3. I deleted the `public/assets` folder which got created after I ran `rake assets:precompile` - another way of deleting the folders is to run the command `bundle exec rake assets:clobber` but this didn't solve the problem
4. I delete the `tmp/cache` folder
5. restarted my server and cleared the browser cache everytime I was trying the sequence 1 thru 4
6. tried changing the order in which I require my stylesheets in application.css

To no avail...

I also have the following setup

1. **application.html.erb**

   `<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>`
2. **application.css**

   *= require self

   *= require_tree .

   *= require custom

   *= require sidebar

   *= require flags/basic

   *= require flags/flags16

   *= require flags/flags32

   *= require font-awesome.min

In application.css in the browser I see this :

[image]

How come my `rake assets:precompile` could break my asset pipeline in development mode ? Thanks in advance for your help, I have spent at least 5 hours trying to figure this out and believed I have done everything I could to figure out a solution...

Answer (score 7):

Precompiled assets will supersede the uncompiled ones.  The documented way to clear them is `bundle exec rake assets:clobber`.  In Rails 3, all this does is delete the `assets` folder.  Perhaps in Rails 4 it's more extensive (I don't have an installation here to test).  Give it a try.

Note if you used an environment qualifier like:

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

to precompile, use the same qualifier to clobber.

However, the other thing that can defeat you is browser caching.  Clear *everything* from the browser cache.  Ideally try a completely different browser. I wasted a day figuring out that Safari requires selection of **Safari** | **Reset...** to purge everything.

Comment: This didn't work unfortunately... It only deleted the assets folder in public directory, which I had already done.

Comment: @Myna Then I'm pretty sure it's browser caching.  The server can't be serving compiled assets that aren't there.

Comment: I cleared the browser cache, I am sure this isn't the problem. The server is NOT serving compiled assets. The compilation of the assets isn't happening anymore. Unbelievable but true... I just don't understand what else it could be...

Comment: @Myna I went through the same thing.  Modern browsers make it very hard to truly clear the cache.  I thought I was going crazy until I finally hit the development server from another machine and everything worked fine.  After that, I finally convinced IE and Firefox to clear by using the "Remove everything" options.  I had been using lesser options that should have worked, but didn't.

Answer (score 2):

Delete your public/assets file and restart server and you will be up and running again and dont run assets:precompile again after